# Non-existent Pygments content on input line "?? PythonTex ??"

Tags: pythontex

I am trying to present my Python script in latex. I have tried using the `pyverbatim` environment and the `\inputpygments` package but neither works, with both yielding the error message *"Package PythonTeX Warning: Non-existent Pygments content on input line xx"*. The compiled document simply typsets *?? PythonTeX ??*

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\begin{pyverbatim} 
print(“Hello, World!”) 
\end{pyverbatim}
\end{document}

Or try using:

\inputpygments{python}{python.py}
```

where the file python.py has been uploaded to the project folder in latex.

[image: compiled doc] [image: error log]

I have also tried including additional packages such as `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` that I noticed others used answering other questions about typesetting one's Python script in Latex, but to no avail.

Comment: do you have pygments installed?

Comment: Do you run `python3 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py --rerun=always <your file>.tex` (depending on your installation, of course) between two `pdflatex` (or other engine)? Your mwe ouputs correct result here.

Comment: @NBur I am sorry, I did not fully understand your question. I am not sure what that is that you are asking whether I run or not. I am using the pdf in Overleaf, I am not sure how exactly it compiles the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not install pygments separately :s  I am working in Overleaf; I have only ever added in packages with `\usepackage`, not via separate installation.

Comment: I have now managed to print the code in my latex document using the Minted package in Overleaf; I just found out about this now. Should I edit this into the question or close the question? I still have not managed to do it using pygments or pyverbatim as I was originally asking though.

Comment: I meant the python program not a latex package. but it is on overleaf as you saw. I do not know if overleaf supports pythontex at all though?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right, it seems that Overleaf does not support pythontex. I will proceed with the minted package. Thanks for your input

Comment: Pythontex use an external python script. As you work on overleaf, I don't know how to proceed (if possible).